# Automapper missing type when mapping database model from entity to viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, automapper

I am a newbie in using automapper and I want to implement it in my project. I am trying to map multiple model from EF to single viewmodel in asp project but before doing that I have encountered a problem as below.
[image]

I tried to follow solution provided as:

1. [Automapper missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105479/automapper-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping)
2. [Automapper missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677889/automapper-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping)

but without any success.
I am using recent automapper.
I tried variation of method to create map such as

```
    config.CreateMap<tblMeeting, MeetingViewModels>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.meetingDetails, input => input.MapFrom(i => new tblMeeting
            {
                meetingId = i.meetingId,
                meetingType = i.meetingType??null,
                startTime = i.startTime,
                finishTime = i.finishTime,
                meetingDate = i.meetingDate,
                meetingNotes = i.meetingNotes,
                meetingVenue = i.meetingVenue
            }));
```

and this

```
            config.CreateMap<tblMeeting, MeetingViewModels>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.meetingDetails.meetingId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.meetingId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.meetingDetails.startTime,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom((s => s.startTime)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.meetingDetails.finishTime,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.finishTime))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.meetingDetails.meetingType,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.meetingType ?? null))

            .ForMember(dest => dest.meetingDetails.meetingDate,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.meetingDate))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.meetingDetails.meetingVenue,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.meetingVenue))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.meetingDetails.meetingNotes,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.meetingNotes));


        });
```

this also

```
             config.CreateMap<tblMeeting, MeetingViewModels>().ConvertUsing<test();

    public class test : ITypeConverter<tblMeeting, MeetingViewModels>
    {


        public MeetingViewModels Convert(tblMeeting source, MeetingViewModels destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            MeetingViewModels m = new MeetingViewModels();

            m.meetingDetails.meetingId = Guid.Parse(source.meetingType.ToString());
            m.meetingDetails.meetingNotes = source.meetingNotes;
            m.meetingDetails.meetingType = Guid.Parse(source.meetingType.ToString());
            m.meetingDetails.meetingDate = source.meetingDate;
            m.meetingDetails.startTime = source.startTime;
            m.meetingDetails.finishTime = source.finishTime;
            m.meetingDetails.meetingVenue = source.meetingVenue;

                return m;
        }
    }
```

but non could solve the problem.
if anyone could help me out it would be of great help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I personally implement `AutoMapper` in my projects:

First create a `MappingConfig` class, generally I put it in `App_Code` folder.

In my projects I probably have different sections in the system, by section I mean different `Areas` or somehow the application needs to be logically separated in different parts like `User Management`, `Meetings` etc whatever you have there...

So from the moment that I can divide the system in logical sections I create a profile class for each section:

Here is an example of profile class:

```
public class GeneralMappingConfigProfile : Profile
{ 
    public GeneralMappingConfigProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<sourceObject, destinationObject>()
                .ForMember(d => d.X, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Y))
    }
}
```

The class above is an example for general mappings but you may have there a Meetings profile class if it is big enough to be distinguished as a section.

Then in my config class I configure all profile classes as below:

```
public class MappingConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            config.AddProfile<GeneralMappingConfigProfile>(); 
            config.AddProfile<MeetingsMappingConfigProfile>();
            //etc
        });
    }
}
```

In the `global.asax` I call the static method like below:

```
MappingConfig.RegisterMappings();
```

Then I can create mappings as many as I see fit in each profile:

I just wrote all this code so you can organize the code better...

For your situation might be a lot of things that might cause this error but refer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677889/automapper-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping). Can you please share more code here because would like to see the `MeetingViewModels` model and the action code because there must be something wrong at the way how you get the tblMeeting object from database.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and I changed the viewmodel and its working fine. What i was doing was adding whole database table as property in viewmodel.

Comment: @shunilkarki if this is a correct answer please mark it as correct so this question is solved and other people would not be confused